# Why tree is not scrollable in displaying dataframe as treeview?

Tags: python, pandas, tkinter

I want to show pandas dataframe as treeview using tkinter. So I filled treeview, located scrollbars, but despite they can be scrollable the tree itself can't do it. Maybe there is problem in method of displaying data. 
Here is my code:

```
def initialize_data(root, data):
    def row_select(event):
        selected_item = tree.selection()[0]
        edit_row_window(tree.item(selected_item, option="values"), columns, selected_item)
    table_frame = tk.Frame(root)
    tree = ttk.Treeview(table_frame, selectmode='browse')
    tree.bind("<Double-1>", row_select)
    columns = data.columns.values.tolist()
    tree["columns"] = columns
    scrl = tk.Scrollbar(table_frame, command=tree.yview(), orient="vertical")
    scrl.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.Y)
    scrl2 = tk.Scrollbar(table_frame, command=tree.xview(), orient="horizontal")
    scrl2.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.X)
    tree.configure(yscrollcommand=scrl.set)
    tree.configure(xscrollcommand=scrl2.set)
    for col in columns:
        tree.column(col, width=75)
        tree.heading(col, text=col)
    for i in range(len(data)):
        tree.insert("", i, values=data.iloc[i, :].tolist())
    tree.pack(side='left', anchor='center')
    table_frame.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM)
```

Picture where i'm trying to scroll
[image: Picture where i try to scroll]

and where i don't
[image: and where i don't]

Thanks.

Comment: When setting the scrollbar command, remove the xview and yview brackets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`command=tree.yview()` needs to be `command=tree.yview`. The same goes for the usage of `xview`.

When you do `command=tree.yview()`, you are *immediately* calling `tree.yview()` and then assigning the result to the `command` attribute. The `command` attribute requires a reference to a callable function.